# Rapid JSON fails to parse in debug mode, but not release

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

Here is the function that writes data to the JSON file initially:

```
template<typename Writer>
inline void ToJSON(Writer& writer) {
 
    writer.StartObject();

    writer.String("msg_type");
    writer.Int(type);

    writer.String("msg");
    writer.String(msg.c_str());

    writer.EndObject();

}
```

This message then gets parsed by this function:

```
static SvrMessage FromJSON(const char* json)
{
    rapidjson::Document d;
    qDebug() << json;

    if (d.Parse<0>(json).HasParseError()) throw std::exception("Unable to parse message");

    auto type = static_cast<SvrMessage::msg_type>(d["msg_type"].GetInt());

    auto msg = d["msg"].GetString();

    return SvrMessage(type, msg);
};
```

When I run the program in release mode, everything works fine and the message is parsed properly. However, in debug mode, the following line will throw an error because it is unable to parse the message.

`if (d.Parse<0>(json).HasParseError()) throw std::exception("Unable to parse message");`

I've looked through all of my project settings as well, and cannot find any discrepancies that would cause the parsing to fail.

Comment: what error does the debug version throw? Knowing the specific one could help solve the problem. If i remember correctly rapid json has an enum that tells you the error reason

Comment: I would start with checking the actual error, using API outlined here: https://rapidjson.org/group___r_a_p_i_d_j_s_o_n___e_r_r_o_r_s.html

Comment: The specific error it is getting is kParseErrorValueInvalid

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, when the JSON was being formed initially, the rapid json stringbuffer GetString() method was returning a char*, which was being freed from the stack in debug mode before it could be used. Changing the return type to a string solved the issue. Here's my fixed method that writes the JSON object:

```
StringBuffer sb;
Writer<StringBuffer> writer(sb);

writer.StartObject();

writer.String("msg_type");
writer.Int(msg.Type());

writer.String("msg");
writer.String(msg.Msg().c_str());

writer.EndObject();

const char* ret_val = sb.GetString();
std::string return_string(ret_val);
return return_string;
```